# EXPORT_SYMBOL causes undefined reference in one direction, but not the other (relocation truncated)

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, arm64

I'm working on the 4.9 Linux kernel on a aarch64 machine, specifically **mm/memory.c** and a custom platform device driver. My goal is to have my device driver communicate some information to hardware that originates in functions in **memory.c**.

At first, I tried the same approach I always use for communicating across (platform) device drivers:

- `EXPORT_SYMBOL` for the respective function in driver A
- Defining the symbol as ***extern*** in driver B and accessing

Usually works like a charm, but this time I came across the following error when linking, with the platform driver **EXPORT**ing and `memory.c` using **extern**:

```
mm/memory.c:164:(.text+0x2a874): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against undefined symbol `my_func'
```

However, if I do the opposite, that is:

- Define and `EXPORT_SYMBOL` a function pointer in `memory.c`
- Assign a pointer to the platform driver function to the exported symbol

... it works!

Specifically...

Platform Driver:

```
void my_func(args){ ... };
EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_func);
```

memory.c:

```
extern void my_func(args);
```

... causes the linker error described above.

But ...

Platform Driver:

```
extern void (*funcptr)(args);

driver_probe() {
...
funcptr = &my_func;
....
}
```

memory.c:

```
void (*funcptr)(args) = NULL;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(funcptr);
```

... works !

A quick google search hinted that the linker error is concerned with the gcc options PIC/PIE, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

It works now ... but WHY? :-)

Comment: Do I correctly understand, that `mm/memory.c` is a file within the *kernel core* (compiled directly into the kernel image), and you build your driver as a *module* (which is intended to be loaded at runtime)? If so, then `mm/memory.c` can use only functions defined in the kernel core, it cannot use functions declared in modules.

Comment: Originally, I had my driver as a module, but by the time I added the symbol I had already switched it from **M** to **Y** in the kernel config.

Comment: If all the code involved is compiled as a part of *kernel core*, then `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is **unrelated to your problem** - this macro affects only on a symbol's usage from the kernel module.

Answer (score 3):

I think the given picture will clarify whats the mistake here. Symbols exported by modules can not be used by the kernel. On the first place kernel won't build giving linker error as you are facing.

[image: kernel symbol exporting knowledge]